# How to know and appoint to last position after success event ajax?

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

Current situation, when task/activity is successfully added, the page will reload go to main project page.

Suggestion to straight away show the successfully added task/activity so user can verify immediately and add the next activity within the same task. This can save time for user add activity , currently need to scroll and find back the tasks/activity to verify and add more.

The question, it is possible to do that? If yes, what is the best keyword or term to google it. Need advise.

In my case, I have datatable that allow user to edit using modal. After the success event, the statement above need to be done.

```
$('#successModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#editModal').modal('hide');
    $('#projectDetail2').empty(); loadtable();
});
```

**UPDATE**

I have use `scrollTop` to get the top value and store in `localStorage`. But when load the page it is not function. I doing like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadtable();
});

function loadtable(){
    if (localStorage.top != 0){
        $(document).scrollTop(localStorage.top);
    }
    else {
        localStorage.top = $(document).scrollTop();

        $.ajax({...});
    }
}
```

Comment: store the value of user last select `task` in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) so whenever your page gets reloaded you can fetch that value and then do further process

Comment: Hi, i have update the code above. it is that way?

Comment: what is `localStorage.top` here ? does it have required value which you needed ?

Comment: Because I also use localStorage at other page for something. so I differenciate by the value stored. So here I want to store scrollTop() inside localStorage.top

Comment: you need to save its value i.e :`localStorage.setItem('top', 'valueyounedtosave');` and then when page gets load get it using `localStorage.getItem('top');` and store in some variable and then perform further logic on this variable .